# How to use a projection matrix with SFML?

Tags: 3d, sfml

I am making a game with a 3D world but 2D sprites. I would like to apply a projection matrix to a [sf::Shape](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6-fr/classsf_1_1Shape.php).

I tried to make a class derived from [sf::Transform](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1Transform.php) that would allow me to use a 4x4 matrix. But the matrix inside sf::Transform is private and there is no way to initialize the last row and the last column.

I could make a new class like sf::Transform and copy every SFML class to use my transform instead of sf::Transform. But this is very "heavy", there must be a better way.

I could make a class that manages a 3D Vertex array and creates a [sf::VertexArray](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1VertexArray.php) from the 3D vertices and a projection matrix. But it would use the CPU for all the calculations.

SFML allows to use [OpenGL](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-opengl.php), but the SFML classes are very convenient and I would like to use them if possible. What I want to do seems to be very close to what SFML can already do.

---

Is there another way I could apply a 4x4 matrix to every vertices of a sf::Shape?

Thank you.